# Derivative of a random variable

Tags: derivatives, random-variables, expected-value

We know that if $X \sim Poisson(\lambda)$ is a Poisson random variable with parameter $\lambda >0$, then

$$\mathbb{E}[X^2] = \lambda + \lambda^2, \quad\text{ and so } \quad \frac{d}{d\lambda}\mathbb{E}[X^2] = 1 + 2\lambda.$$

I was thinking if, on the other hand, we could write

$$\frac{d}{d\lambda}\mathbb{E}[X^2] = \mathbb{E}[\frac{d}{d\lambda}X^2] = \mathbb{E}[2XX'],$$

where $X'$ denotes the derivative of $X$ with respect to $\lambda$, can we make sense of the expression $XX'$?

That is, do you think there is a way to compute $\mathbb{E}[2XX']$ directly?

Comment: It makes sense to consider the $\lambda\mapsto \lambda+\lambda^2$ and its derivative, as this is a map from $\mathbb R$ to $\mathbb R$. But not "the derivative of $X$ with respect to $\lambda$" - as $X$ is, in general, a measurable function defined on an arbitrary probability space on which differentiation need not be defined.

So the answer is "no, we cannot make sense of the expression $XX'$."

Comment: Random variables can be thought as "measurements from an experiment" or "processed information from the experiment". So they are in general lacking any geometric structures necessary for discussing continuity,  letting alone differentiability. When they are parametrized by time and/or space so as to define "random-variable-valued function" or equivalently "function-valued random variable", then you can start talking about regularity of that function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\lambda$ is a parameter of the *probability distribution*, not of the random variable *per se*. $~$ We *may* take the derivative of an expectation for a random variable with respect to such a parameter, **however** this is *not* the expectation for the derivative of the random variable. $~$ This is what happens to a discrete random variable:
$$\begin{align}\dfrac{\mathrm d ~~}{\mathrm d \lambda}\mathsf E(X^2)&=\sum_{n} n^2\cdot\dfrac{\mathrm d\mathsf P(X = n)}{\mathrm d \lambda}&\neq& \sum_{n}2n\dfrac{\mathrm d n}{\mathrm d \lambda}\cdot\mathsf P(X=n)\end{align}$$

Comment: Thank you! It makes more sense now